# Recommended way to populate a fresh MongoDB instance with data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a local container created with Docker with MongoDB & an express node server

What is the recommended way to populate it with new data?
1) Use the cli
2) Using Mongoose
3) Use a GUI such as Compass

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a 'correct' way to do this, but I've run a couple of 'seeds' files for my projects:

https://github.com/rmgreenstreet/surfShop/blob/master/seeds.js

https://github.com/rmgreenstreet/yelpcamp/blob/master/seeds.js

https://github.com/rmgreenstreet/custom-forms/blob/master/seeds.js

I almost wish there was some kind of niche field/need/position for being able to generate fake data!

The point is that you'll need to set and understand the structure of your data and essentially go through a bunch of nested loops for any connected/dependent data types.

Now if you're working with a SQL database, I'm totally clueless. That's next on my "things to learn" once I feel more comfortable with Javascript/NoSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm basicly a front-end dev so I also feel a lot more comfortable with js and js based stuff, just need a basic db for a project I'm running so I'm trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

This would possibly depend on the usecase here,

Answer would be:

MONGOOSE : If you are planning to deploy an application using express. As mongoose goes hand in hand with express. (https://medium.com/@SigniorGratiano/mongoose-and-express-68994fcfdeff) As in many stacks like MEAN, MERN.

GUI like Compass: When you have to visualise the data or do ONE TIME OPERATIONS.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the link its a great article